# OpenCV: refine contours that are similar to rectangles

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, canny-operator

I was working on rectangle detection software, that should detect any rectangle on a given surface. After doing some research I came up with the following:

1. Apply Gaussian Blur on grayscale image
2. Detect Edges with Canny, using Otsu thresholds
3. MorphEx with rect
4. Findcontours

This yields decent results, however in some cases contour is not perfect. Which can be seen in the following images [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLiPP.png) , [detected contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUrhN.png).

I was thinking about convex hull, but then even the contours that aren't rectangles may be misinterpreted as rectangles. Maybe continue the contours in a straight line and calculate intersection points?

I am stuck. Any tips on how to refine the contours?

Here's the code for reference (Java on Android):

```
    detectedEdges = grayImg.clone();
    Size size = new Size(9, 9);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayImg, grayImg, size, 0);

    double otsu = Imgproc.threshold(grayImg.clone(),new Mat(),0,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY|Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

    Imgproc.Canny(grayImg, detectedEdges, otsu/2, otsu);
    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(4,4));
    Imgproc.morphologyEx(detectedEdges.clone(),detectedEdges,Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel);
    contours = new ArrayList<>();

    Imgproc.findContours(detectedEdges.clone(),contours,new Mat(),Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    if (contours.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No contours found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }

    for(MatOfPoint c : contours){
        MatOfPoint2f contour = new MatOfPoint2f(c.toArray());

        double length  = Imgproc.arcLength(contour,true);
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour,contour,0.02*length,true);
        if(contour.total() == 4){
            //found a rect! DO something
        }
    }

    Imgproc.drawContours(grayImg,contours,-1,new Scalar(255,225,255), 2);
```

Comment: do yourself a favour and invest time in better images. your image looks like you used a pinhole camera from 1856...  crap in = crap out

Comment: The image source is a smartphone camera. If you didn't notice, the image was blurred on purpose, to decrease the amount of "distractions". Increasing image resolution didn't change anything besides slowing down the overall performance. According to you providing super high detailed image in, will result in detecting better rectangles? That unfortunately is not the case.

Comment: Sorry I cannot read you rmind. I only saw an absolutely terrible image that was declared as "original". To me this usually means it's the original, not something preprocessed. I don't say that you necessarily get better results with higher resolution but you always want the best possible input you can get in your world (limited by money, bandwidth and whatnot) and users here tend to spend a lot of energy on processing bad images which they could often easily improve. and if you want to improve the output of a system you always start at its input.

Comment: Well I do understand that, sorry if I sounded too aggressive... Anyways I did try with a higher res image, but the results were almost exactly the same. And as I aim for real time performance, the tiny gains with higher res are simply not worth it...